# Python class method

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-nova

I have a class instance of type `<class 'openstack_dashboard.api.nova.Server'>`:

```
 >>>print instance
 >>><Server: {'id': u'9fa3b2e9-a76b-44ae-be75-968d4010eb27', 
              'links': [{u'href': u'http://10.0.3.129:8774/v2/344f7fa036fc45008130cdf1cffac019/servers/9fa3b2e9-a76b-44ae-be75-968d4010eb27', u'rel': u'self'}, 
                        {u'href': u'http://10.0.3.129:8774/344f7fa036fc45008130cdf1cffac019/servers/9fa3b2e9-a76b-44ae-be75-968d4010eb27', u'rel': u'bookmark'}]}>
 >>> print dir(instance)
 >>> ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', 
      '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', 
      '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', 
      '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 
      '__weakref__', '_apiresource', '_attrs', 'image_name', 
      'internal_name', 'request']
```

I want to get the `'id'` (`'9fa3b2e9-a76b-44ae-be75-968d4010eb27'`). 
What should I do ? Thank you !

Comment: I think `print instance.id`

Comment: @p99will -- unlikely.  There's no `id` attribute if you look at the output of `dir`.

Comment: How did you create the instance?

Comment: instance = api.nova.server_create(request,
                                   context['name'],
                                   context['image_id'],
                                   context['flavor'],
                                   None,
                                   None,
                                   None,
                                   dev_mapping,
                                   nics=nics,
                                   availability_zone=avail_zone,
                                   instance_count=int(context['count']))

Comment: @changzhi What is `api`? What framework do you use?

Comment: did you try `instance['id']`?

Comment: In Openstack , it can create a vm by this 'api' ...

Comment: When I try **instance['id']?** it occures  TypeError: 'Server' object is unsubscriptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what I can see in the [source](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/horizon/_modules/openstack_dashboard/api/nova.html#Server), `Server` inherits from the common [APIResourceWrapper](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/horizon/_modules/openstack_dashboard/api/base.html#APIResourceWrapper), which in turn implements `__gatattr__` so that `id`, while it's not exactly an object's own attribute, will be taken from the internal container `self._apiresource`.

So, `instance.id` will work and will effectively return `instance._apiresource.id`.

Comment: Oh. Could you tell should I do ?

Comment: If you want to get the id, just do `instance.id`.

Answer (score 1):

Class `openstack_dashboard.api.nova.Server` inherits from [`openstack_dashboard.api.base.APIResourceWrapper`](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/horizon/api/openstack_dashboard.api.base.html#openstack_dashboard.api.base.APIResourceWrapper) and this class has defined [`__getattr__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) method which uses `self._attrs`, so I think it should be possible to read `id` in this way:

```py
print(instance.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work now for you, but it's implementation-dependent:

```
import re
printed = instance.__str__() #might also be __repr__()
m = re.search("'id'\s*:\s*u'([\w+\-]+)'", printed)
m.groups(0)[0] #returns 9fa3b2e9-a76b-44ae-be75-968d4010eb27
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote :). Well, that's why I answered in the first place. And that proves I can see into the future so i've put 'might' and 'implementaion-dependent' up-there.

Comment: The downvote is mine. Sorry, I usually don't mock anyone that straight, but this makes even better codewtf than infamous `if (boolvalue.toString().length() == 4) {...}`.

Comment: You have just given me a great code snippet that I know going to save my butt someday. Thank you bereal!.